# building different projects into 1 project using maven

Tags: maven-2, maven, maven-3

I have a project which has 20 different projects this was build using ant.now i want to move it to maven build.I have created jars for all the 20 projects + 1 main project.I need to build this main project to get the app running.I am working with NetBeans 6.7.1.How am i going to integrate this project and deploy it?Please help !

Answer (score 0):

In maven, you can either create a [multi-module project](http://www.sonatype.com/books/mvnref-book/reference/pom-relationships-sect-pom-best-practice.html#pom-relationships-sect-multi-vs-inherit) or add the other projects [as dependencies](http://www.sonatype.com/books/mvnref-book/reference/pom-relationships-sect-project-dependencies.html).

I prefer the first approach, because it lets you build everything in one run (and that's exactly the reason why others prefer the second version, because they want their projects to be independent of each other).

Either way, run [`mvn deploy`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/deploy-mojo.html) or use the [`maven-release-plugin`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-release-plugin/) on the individual projects or the root project of a multi-module project.

Comment: Thanks a Lot.    But by creating a multi-module project i can get a POM file of my parent project.How can i deploy it? will i need a Jar file?.Now i also tried with the second way.But the Maven-dependency-plugin is not been regognized.It is showing an error of Plugion not found in repository.I am using maven 2.0.9.Maven-dependecy-plugin 2.1.Please provide help for both these doubts

Comment: @Soney first of all: don't use Maven 2.0.9. It's old and buggy. Use either Maven 3.0.x or Maven 2.2.1 . Then, to deploy all modules on a multi-file project, call mvn deploy in the root project. That will deploy everything, including the root pom.

Comment: Thanks Floyd.will get back to you soon.May need help.:-)

Comment: @Soney calling me Floyd is a bad start if you want my help. My name's Sean :-)